# How can i build a dynamic scaffolding in a jsp depending the subclass of an entity?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, scaffold

Well,
I have the Vehicle Class,
And I have a car, a bike, a motorcycle, and other classes with inheritance, and the administrator of vehicles (CRUD).

When I search all the vehicles, the administration service shows me a list with all the vehicles reported in the system, when I select one, the action must send me to a jsp with the information of the vehicle plus its unique characteristics, like the wings in an airplane, where i can modify and delete it.

I want that depending the type of the vehicle, the jsp could show all the properties of the vehicle.
And I need to make the process automatic, when i add a new type of vehicle or a new part, not be necessary to change the jsp or the action.

I use JavaWeb in this project, with hibernate and struts2.

Thank You for the help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Will it be nessesary to recompile the classes when "a new type of vehicle or a new part" is added?

Comment: You can try to achieve something like that with reflections.